# How to integrate two create react app projects or their builds?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have created two create-react-app projects one for mobile UI and other for desktop UI because of some conditions. I want to integrate both of them and put on server so appropriate UI is loaded on devices. Is their way to integrate their builds while putting on server or any other way?

Comment: I would advice having one codebase that is responsive.

Comment: I know but as I told it is already done so now what can be done?

Comment: In your case, because it's done. I would create a static html page to redirect to one or another project depending on device and serve each one in a subfolder

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia Can I do it on builds? I would also like to add that these two projects have same components with diff UIs so they actually present thing so I cannot do something like www.example.com/mobile for mobile ui if that's what you are suggesting

Comment: You can build each one separately and then move build folders into a common folder, rename those or something like that, as far as I know is not posible to do that without ejecting a Create React App

Comment: Ok, then my approach is not a good option. Then, IMO, should be to create a common library for your shared components? I can't figure out other way

Comment: You can internally build and deploy two projects, and just the web server serves the right one depending on the user agent.

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI Seems good idea but what to do on server what config do I need for this?

Comment: depends on what webserver you are using. what are you using exactly ?

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI Using shared web server